# How to accumulate items in a list field using Aggregate framework of Mongo in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate, grouping, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following entities:

```
public class MyEntity {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class MyPageItem {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Ids { get; set; } = new List<string>{};
}
```

And the following grouping:

```
IMongoCollection<MyEntity> myCollection = MongoClient.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").GetCollection<MyEntity>("MyEntity");
    
myCollection.Aggregate()
                .Sort(new SortDefinitionBuilder<MyEntity>().Ascending("code"))
                .Group(
                        x => x.Code,
                        g => new MyPageItem {
                            Code = g.Select(x => x.Code).Last(),
                            Total = g.Select(x => x.Amount).Sum(),
                            Ids = //how to append Ids in this field?
                        }
                    )
                .ToListAsync();
```

I would like to add all Ids in the `List<string> Ids`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `IList` interface will cause an error when your query gets deserialized but you can switch to:

```
public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
```

and then use:

```
collection.Aggregate()
            .Group(
                x => x.Code,
                gr => new MyPageItem()
                {
                    Code = gr.Key,
                    Total = gr.Sum(x => x.Amount),
                    Ids = gr.Select(y => y.Id).ToList()
                }
            )
```